io.smallrye.mutiny.TimeoutException when a Quarkus application in Podman container tries to get a key from Redis installed in same host machine
Environment:

Debian 11
Podman 4.8.3
Quarkus 3.12.3
Java 17.0.11
Mandrel 23.r20
Redis 7.2.4

Application:

Quarkus application on Podman container
Redis server on host machine (host that runs the container)

Problem:
ERROR [io.qua.ver.htt.run.QuarkusErrorHandler] (executor-thread-1) HTTP Request to /contrato_fatores failed, error id: 37427554-c0eb-4f69-b4bf-23bb76c33754-1: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: 
io.smallrye.mutiny.TimeoutException
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:107)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:344)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:205)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:452)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invokePropagateNotFound$6(SynchronousDispatcher.java:275)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:154)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:321)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:157)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invokePropagateNotFound(SynchronousDispatcher.java:260)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.RequestDispatcher.service(RequestDispatcher.java:84)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.dispatch(VertxRequestHandler.java:151)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler$1.run(VertxRequestHandler.java:97)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:599)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.doRunWith(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2516)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2495)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1521)
        at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:11)
        at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:11)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base@17.0.12/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads.threadStartRoutine(PlatformThreads.java:885)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads.threadStartRoutine(PlatformThreads.java:860)

I've already tried doing:

podman run --network=host
podman-compose with network_mode=host
If run the container from another machine the communication works

Apparently it's a problem with the communication between Quarkus in container and the host machine. We use the blocking approach to use the Redis with RedisDataSource from io.quarkus:quarkus-redis-client, but apparently the Quarkus uses the smallrye.mutiny under the hood.
